# How to have a generic vector inside a class for which the type is unknown

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to have an array class using a vector where type of vector is to be decided by user.

```
class Array {
    vector<type> V
    int size;
    string type;
public:
    Array() {
        this->size = 0;
        this->type = "void";
        // V = vector<depending_on_type>(size);
    }

    Array(int size, string type) {
        this->size = size;
        this->type = type;
        if(type == "int") {
            // initialize as vector<int>
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using pointers and pointers to pointers but nothing works so far.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ does not work this way. C++ is strongly typed. The type of all objects must be known and specified at compile time.

Comment: `template<typename type> class Array` ... could be a start.

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Instead of `string type`, consider using an [enumerated type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum). Much swifter and lighter-weight than a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you may need a `templates`. Just check this below code, it works for me:

```
template <class T>
class Array {
    std::vector<T> V;
    int size;
    std::string type;
public:
    Array(): size(0),type("void"), V( T() ) {
    }

    Array(int s, std::string t): size(s), type(t), V( T() ) {
        if(type == "int") {
            //do-some initialization
            V.push_back(100);
            V.push_back(200);
        }
    }

    void print_vector() {
        std::cout << V[0] << ", " << V[1] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array<int> a(10, "int");
    a.print_vector();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to want a runtime dependent type; templates are compile time only.

Comment: Question is "type" of vector decided by "user" !